# kubectl config set proxy

Tags: proxy, kubectl

I can't connect to my cluster servers directly.
How can I set HTTP_PROXY in kubectl configfile?
Using kubectl for windows.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- name: "dev"
  cluster:
    server: "https://10.100.12.12:9006/k8s/clusters/c-jm5ws"
    certificate-authority-data: "LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSUJoekNDQ\
      VM2Z0F3SUJBZ0lCQURBS0JnZ3Foa2pPUFFRREFqQTdNUnd3R2dZRFZRUUtFeE5rZVc1aGJXbGoKY\
      kdsemRHVnVaWEl0YjNKbk1Sc3dHUVlEVlFRREV4SmtlVzVoYldsamJHbHpkR1Z1WlhJdFkyRXdIa"
```

Answer (score 33):

very hard to find on google..
but found the solution:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- name: "dev"
  cluster:
    proxy-url: http://user:password@proxy:port
    server: "https://10.100.12.12:9006/k8s/clusters/c-jm5ws"
    ...
```

Comment: Hello, glad that you found the solution. Could you please add the links to the sites you've found it? Also adding to the answer, there is a feature request on github for this option to be included in the Kubernetes documentation: https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/26687

Comment: @DawidKruk This feature is mentioned here
https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/351#issuecomment-626752837

Comment: indeed very hard to find. the kubectl proxy stuff is shadowing it all....  and using proxy-url instead of http-proxy like everyone else doesnt help either....

Answer (score 0):

Update the cluster in your kube-config to use proxy-url:

```bash
kubectl config set clusters.dev.proxy-url <proxy-url>
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/#proxy

`kubectl config set --help` or https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_config_set/